# How to get data in proper shape to feed to LSTM layer in keras for sequence to sequence prediction

Tags: python-3.x, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have dataframe as following for time series where `SETTLEMENTDATE` is index. I want to take first row, i.e `2018-11-01 14:30:00` and values of `T_1`, `T_2`, `T_3`, `T_4`, `T_5`, `T_6` as a sequence and predict sequence of `DE_1`, `DE_2`, `DE_3`, `DE_4`.

I am using keras for Sequence to sequence time series using LSTM. I tried to take `T_1` to `T_6` as input dataframe `'X'` and `DE_1` to `DE_4` as output dataframe `'y'`. I reshaped it using `X = np.array(X)` `y = np.array(y)` and then `X = X.reshape(4,6,1)` and `y = y.reshape(4,4,1)` to feed to `batch_input_shape()` but it does not work.

How to get data in proper shape to feed to LSTM layer?

```
                      T_1     T_2     T_3     T_4     T_5     T_6    DE_1    DE_2    DE_3    DE_4
SETTLEMENTDATE                                          
2018-11-01 14:30:00 1645.82 1623.23 1619.09 1581.94 1538.20 1543.48 1624.23 1722.85 1773.77 1807.04
2018-11-01 15:00:00 1628.60 1645.82 1623.23 1619.09 1581.94 1538.20 1722.85 1773.77 1807.04 1873.53
2018-11-01 15:30:00 1624.23 1628.60 1645.82 1623.23 1619.09 1581.94 1773.77 1807.04 1873.53 1889.06
2018-11-01 16:00:00 1722.85 1624.23 1628.60 1645.82 1623.23 1619.09 1807.04 1873.53 1889.06 1924.57
```

Comment: You have to show us how you have set up the LSTM layer because input shape depends on if you have set `return_state` or `return_sequences` to `True`.

Comment: Hi @Novak, I have given return_sequences=True.

Answer (score 1):

LSTM accepts two arguments: `input_shape` and `batch_input_shape`. The difference is in convention that `input_shape` does not contain the batch size, while `batch_input_shape` is the full input shape including the batch size.

LSTM layer is a recurrent layer, hence it expects a 3-dimensional input `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. That's why the correct specification is `input_shape=(6, 1)` or `batch_input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, 6, 1)`, where `BATCH_SIZE` is the size of your batch.

I hope it helps :)